# Get data from 3 table with Inner Join MySQL php

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
include '../incs/connect.php';
    $q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT appl_reg_details.appl_id, appl_reg_details.apl_name, appl_reg_details.apl_email, rp_test_result.appl_status, rp_intv_result.intv_obt_marks
                          FROM appl_reg_details
                          INNER JOIN rp_test_result ON appl_reg_details.appl_id = rp_test_result.appl_id
                          INNER JOIN rp_intv_result ON rp_test_result.appl_id = rp_intv_result.appl_id
                          GROUP BY appl_reg_details.appl_id
                          ");
    WHILE($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
    {
        echo $row=['appl_id']." - ";
        echo $row=['apl_name']." - ";
        echo $row=['intv_obt_marks']." - ";
        echo $row=['appl_status']." -";
        echo $row=['apl_email']."<br/>";
    }
```

I have 3 tables and i want to get data of 3 field from table1, of 1 field from table 2 and table 3 each, i have found that inner join can do this, when i run this it says 'Notice: Array to string conversion',
help to correct this or give a new way please

Comment: `echo $row['appl_id']." - ";`   (remove the equals sign)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query looks fine at first glance.

The problem is with the lines below it. They include an unnecessary `=`:

`echo $row=['apl_email']."<br/>";`

These lines should be like this:

`echo $row['apl_email']."<br/>";`

Comment: I guess it depends on who's doing the glancing

Comment: Someone trying to fix the error in the question...?

Answer (score 0):

Performance benefits aside, GROUP BY serves no purpose here other than to confuse the result set. Try something like this instead, and fix the coding errors identified by rjdown:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.appl_id
              , d.apl_name
              , d.apl_email
              , t.appl_status
              , i.intv_obt_marks
           FROM appl_reg_details d
           JOIN rp_test_result t
             ON t.appl_id = d.appl_id 
           JOIN rp_intv_result i 
             ON r.appl_id = i.appl_id;
```

Comment: Can you help me for  WHERE in this query, SELECT appl_reg_details.appl_id, appl_reg_details.apl_name, appl_reg_details.apl_email, rp_test_result.appl_status, rp_intv_result.intv_obt_marks
         FROM appl_reg_details
         INNER JOIN rp_test_result ON appl_reg_details.appl_id = rp_test_result.appl_id
         INNER JOIN rp_intv_result ON rp_test_result.appl_id = rp_intv_result.appl_id
         GROUP BY appl_reg_details.appl_id WHERE appl_reg_details.jb_id=1

Comment: @ShahidRasheed WHERE precedes GROUP BY  - although here it's irrelevant because, as I've already explained, your GROUP BY clause is inappropriate in this context

Comment: thanks, i have removed Group By and Where started working, thanks again for help